# SugarCRM SOAP test call fails

Tags: soap, sugarcrm

I am attempting to test a SugarCRM Soap connection using the following code:

```
<?
define('sugarEntry', TRUE);
require_once('include/nusoap/nusoap.php');
$sugarclient = new nusoapclient('http://www.mycrmurl.com/soap.php?wsdl',true);


echo $sugarclient->call('test', 'test string');
?>
```

Unfortunately, the test call returns NULL. Thoughts on how to begin troubleshooting?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not familiar with a SugarCRM SOAP method called `test`, so unless it's a custom method you made yourself, I'd try with some simple valid calls. (Tested with Sugar CE 6.2).

```
<?php
require_once('include/nusoap/lib/nusoap.php');

$myWsdl = 'http://www.mycrmurl.com/soap.php?wsdl';
$myAuth = array(
        'user_name' => 'will',
        'password' => MD5('will'),
        'version' => '0.1'
);
$soapClient = new nusoap_client($myWsdl,true);

$loginParams = array('user_auth' => $myAuth, 'application_name' => 'MyApp');
$loginResult = $soapClient->call('login', $loginParams);
$sessionId = $loginResult['id'];
echo $sessionId;
?>
```

If the above still gives you problems, try the following:

- Look in the web server log (Is the call getting through)
- Enable the SugarCRM logging and set the level to debug
- Either enable PHP error output or make PHP log errors to a log file
- Use e.g. SoapUI to test SOAP call
- See [question 5396302](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5396302/344951) for a more thorough SOAP example
- Check the [SugarCRM SOAP documentation](http://www.sugarcrm.com/crm/support/documentation/SugarCommunityEdition/6.2/-docs-Developer_Guides-Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.2.0-Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.2.0.html#9000432)

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
$result = $sugarclient->call('test', 'test string');
echo print_r ($result);
```

It will print the array result, if you just want to see the error description do this:

```
$result = $sugarclient->call('test', 'test string');
echo $result['error']['description'];
```

The result is a multidimensional array.