# Connect to SugarCRM REST services with SoapUI

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, soapui, sugarcrm

I saw somewhere in net (like [SugarCRM SOAP test call fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902452/sugarcrm-soap-test-call-fails)), that some people use SoapUI to access SugarCRM SOAP or REST web services, with urls like `http://ip/sugarcrm/service/v2/soap.php` and `http://ip/sugarcrm/service/v2/rest.php`, respectively. I tried it, with 'New SoapUI Project' wizard, and putting that urls in 'Initial WSDL/WADL:". But I only get error messages:

> "Error loading [http://ip/sugarcrm/service/v2/soap.php] org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Unexpected character encountered: 'c' ", in SOAP case;

and

> "Error loading [http://ip/sugarcrm/service/v2/rest.php] org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Unexpected character encountered (lex state 8): ',' ", in REST case.

I tried with NetBeans too, like I explained in [Add SugarCRM REST services to NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701666/add-sugarcrm-rest-services-to-netbeans), but the error there is different (but still get an error).

Could this be an issue of SugarCRM or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the wsdl for the SOAP service, which is found at `http://ip/sugarcrm/service/v2/soap.php?wsdl`

Comment: Thank you, Storgaard. It works with the "?wsdl" in the end. But I need to work with REST services, not SOAP services (SOAP connection was a test only). And adding "?wadl" doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think there is a wadl for the rest service. You need to program/interface manually with the services based on the description in the rest.php or the documentation/examples. Moreover, the rest service only accepts json/php-serialize, so I guess you need to manually define a json request in soapui for the rest url you provided above.

Comment: Hi @KåreWernerStorgaard could you look to this question please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10529238/why-am-i-getting-an-error-when-loading-a-webservice-in-soap-ui