# How to interact SugarCRM data with Android application?

Tags: android, sugarcrm

I am working first time in SugarCRM I have really no idea regarding this. so please give me basic idea and work flow about this. how to interact with Android application ?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate? Are you triyng to access SugarCRM data from an Android app?

Comment: Thanks!  Kåre Werner Storgaard

Comment: And I want to access data from my android application. and I saw your profile also and I found that you have much knowledge about SugarCRM, please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SugarCRM has a SOAP web service API, so basically consume the wsdl's from your android app with for instance ksoap2-android.

SugarCRM SOAP API:

- [SugarCRM documentation](http://www.sugarcrm.com/crm/support/documentation/SugarCommunityEdition/6.4/-docs-Developer_Guides-Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.4.0-Sugar_Developer_Guide_640.html#9000434)
- [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396302/where-is-sugarfulltest-version2-php-sugar-crm-and-soap) (based on php client)

Android k2soap library:

- [Documentation](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/)
- [Example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-android/index.html)